# Custom function for API Django Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Working on custom API function that works on creating and updating Ratings

when I try to test run the function on Postman I get the following error:

`IntegrityError at /api/movies/1/rate_movie/`

`UNIQUE constraint failed: API_rating.user_id, API_rating.movie_id`

so I do not know if the flaw could be on code or what 
here is the code below

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
def rate_movie(self, request, pk=None):

    if 'stars' in request.data:

        movie = Movie.objects.get(id=pk)
        #user = request.user #Can not use now due to lack of auth, login
        user = User.objects.get(id=1)
        stars = request.data['stars']

        try:
            rating = Rating.objects.get(user=user.id, movie=movie.id)
            rating.stars = stars
            rating.save()
            serializer = RatingSerializer
            response = {'message': 'Rating Updated', 'results': serializer.data}
            return Response(response, status=HTTP_200_OK)

        except:
            rating = Rating.objects.create(user=user, movie=movie, stars=stars)
            serializer = RatingSerializer
            response = {'message': 'Rating Created', 'results': serializer.data}
            return Response(response, status=HTTP_200_OK)

    else:
        response = {'message':'Stars not selected for rating'}
        return Response(response, status=HTTP_400_bad_request)
```

Lastly here is a picture of the sample test I made when I got the error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is failing silently and caught by your generic `except`

Looks like your `Rating` model has a unique constraint that only allows a user to rate a movie once, which makes sense. Therefore you can't do `Rating.objects.create(user=user, movie=movie, stars=stars)` if another rating exists from `user` to `movie`.

Instead, you need to update the existing one if it exists, otherwise create a new one. Something like:

```
Rating.objects.update_or_create(user=user, movie=movie, defaults={stars:stars})
```

It looks like this is what you're trying to do, but

- Don't use generic `except` unless really necessary! It can hide your errors and lead to bugs. In this case it hides the fact that:
- You need to do `serializer = RatingSerializer()` (with the parens()), or better yet `serializer = self.get_serializer()` and define a `serializer_class` class attribute

Comment: I did this that which you mentioned

```rating = Rating.objects.update_or_create(user=user, movie=movie, defaults={stars:stars})```

and I also added the
```serializer = RatingSerializer()```

So I then test ran it just now on postman I get the following error

```AttributeError at /api/movies/1/rate_movie/```

```'tuple' object has no attribute 'stars'```

Comment: `update_or_create` returns a tuple: the object, and a boolean that says if it was created or it already existed. Therefore, you can do `rating, was_created = Rating.objects.update_or_create(...)`. That being said, you don't even need to set rating.stars because `update_or_create` does that for you through the `defaults` argument. Also, please include full error logs and line number when you post errors.